# sending html dropdownlist selected value from javascript to model database in mvc 2

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Hi i have an html dropdownlist that gets and displays values from my database perfectly, now i have a javascript method to get the selected value from the list, i dont know if this script is even working but either way how do i get the selected value into my controller.cs code? Any input will be greatly appreciated.

```
`<h2>Create New Task</h2>
            <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
            <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<fieldset>
<legend>Create Task</legend>

<label for="Task">Department</label>
<div class="editor-field">
<%: Html.DropDownList( "lsttasks", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["depies"], "Department"), new { onchange = "onSelectedIndexChanged(this)" })%>
<br />`
```

```html
 <h2>Create New Task</h2>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
  <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Create Task</legend>

      <label for="Task">Department</label>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownList( "lsttasks", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData[ "depies"], "Department"), new { onchange="onSelectedIndexChanged(this)" })%>
          <br />
      </div>


      <label for="Task">Competency</label>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownList( "lsttasks", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData[ "compies"], "Competency1"), new { onchange="onSelectedIndexChanged(this)" })%>

          <%-- <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model=>Model.Competency) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessage( "Name", "*") %>--%>
      </div>

      <label for="Task">Task</label>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Task_Name) %>
          <%: Html.ValidationMessage( "Name", "*") %>
      </div>

      <label for="Task">Description</label>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Description) %>
          <%: Html.ValidationMessage( "Description", "*") %>
      </div>

      <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="CreateTask" />
    </fieldset>
    <% } %>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function onSelectedIndexChanged(select) {
          var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
          document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = text;
        }
      </script>
      </asp:Content>
```

Comment: You mean without a form submit? An AJAX call I guess, that is triggered on the selectbox change.

Comment: Oh i used the default submit button that comes with the create view  <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="CreateTask" />

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984916/mvc-dropdownlist-populate-from-one-db-table-and-send-to-another-db-table/28985293#28985293
I found the answer here!!!!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script you had used 
var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
its better to select id's of the corresponding dropdown text,then your problem will be solved.
eg:var text = $("#id_of_the_dropdown").Val();
to select the id,you can pass id through hidden field.

Comment: Thanks for the response @shajeer i have changed my script to to what you suggested but im still having trouble sending the selected value to my model.department and the other one to model.competency. with a normal html:textbox it would be as below <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model=>Model.Competency) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessage( "Name", "*") %> but now how do i send selected list item to model.competency

Comment: write another function to save eg:function OnSave(e) {}

Comment: Thanks I'll work on that, at the moment i found something on someone elses question which works directly:-   <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Department,new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["depies"], "Department")) %>