# MVC DropDownList populate from one DB table and send to another DB table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I would like to have a dropdownlist which pulls data from a qualification table and then on HttpPost it stores the value selected in the dropdownlist to a "qualification" column on the employee table. I'm very new to MVC and I don't really know the syntax very well. I also don't know how to use jquery, vb etc. so sorry if there is a post out there that covers this and I've not seen it because I don't know what I'm looking at.

This is currently my best attempt at doing this:

**Controller:**

```
private Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
...
...
...
    // GET: /Home/CreateEmp
            public ActionResult CreateEmp()
            {
                ViewBag.QualList = new SelectList(db.Qualifications, "Id", "qual");
                return View();
            }
            // POST: /Home/CreateEmployee
            [HttpPost, ActionName("CreateEmployee")]
            public ActionResult CreateEmpResult(Employee emp)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Employees.Add(emp);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                ViewBag.QualList = new SelectList(db.Qualifications, "Id", "qual", emp.qualification);
                return View(emp);
            }
```

**Create Employee View:**

```
@model MvcDropDownList.Models.Employee
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEmployee", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <table>
        <!-- other fields removed for sake of simplicity -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("Select Your Qualification:")
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("QualList", "--Select--")
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    }
```

**Table Structure:**

> Qualifications Table: Id, qual
>
> Employee Table: Id, firstName, surName, gender, qualification

My code successfully gets the data from the "Qualification" table but doesn't post it to the "qualification" column in the "employee" table.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind your dropdownlist to the model you're returning when clicking the Save button.

In other words, this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("QualList", "--Select--")
```

Should turn into something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Qualification_Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.QualList)
```

**Edit** As Stephen Muecke pointed out, you need to cast the Viewbag value to a `SelectList`.

**Note** There are multiple possibilities for `DropDownListFor()`. I only picked the easiest one for clarity's sake, but you could add your optional label etc.

This binds it to your model (`emp`):

```
public ActionResult CreateEmpResult(Employee emp)
```

**Note**: If your `Employee` class was correctly set up and has the needed Foreign keys (link to the Qualification table), there should already be a `.Qualification_Id` (or similar name) in your `Employee` class (assuming that class is your actual database entity).

These changes will cover everything you need:

- The dropdownlist now writes the selected value into `emp.Qualification_Id`.
- In your controller method, you save `emp` to the db.
- EF will use the FK fields (`emp.Qualification_Id`) to make sure the correct values will be written in the new Employee row that will be created in the database.

As a general rule, always try to bind controls (dropdownlists, textboxes, ...) to a property of your model. if you do that, you don't need to write specific code to do basically the same.

Comment: Note it needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Qualification_Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.QualList)` - you need to cast `ViewBag.QualList`

Comment: I thought MVC5 fixed that, but you appear to be right. Updating the answer :)

Comment: clearly I'm missing something... I have set-up the employee table with a "qualId" FK and added the following code to the View:
`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.QualId, (SelectList)ViewBag.QualList)`

In the controller, the post action has:
`ViewBag.QualList = new SelectList(db.Qualifications, "Id", "qual", emp.qualId);`

I thought this would work, Am I missing something??

Comment: also, I have MVC4 (Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the `ViewBag = ...` part. Setting the ViewBag should be done on the method when *loading* the Create page (GET request), not when you receive the POST from it (by then, the user should have already selected the correct entry from the dropdownlist). Secondly, did **you** put a `QualId` column/field in the Employee entity, or did you add a relation between the entities? Depending on if you work Code First, Model First or DB First, you have to let EF generate its own FK field based on the relation you set up between the two entities.

Comment: Minor addition: when I say setting the Viewbag shouldn't be done in the POST, I mean that it's not needed for the act of saving the Employee to the db. If you set the Viewbag in the POST Method, you're setting it up to be used on the *following* page. Doesn't mean you shouldn't do it, but that it's irrelevant for the problem you're currently facing.

Comment: I created a "qualId" in employee manually and then set-up a `CONSTRAINT [qualid] FOREIGN KEY ([qualId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Qualifications] ([Id])` in the employee table to link the qualifications "Id" key to the "qualId" key in the Employee table. How does the EF work in my case?
...
I will remove the "ViewBag" in the post action (I was following another forum post before this to get it to work)

Comment: I can't fully answer this in a single comment, and I'd need more information about your setup. *Unless you take a DB first approach*, you shouldn't be manually setting up the DB tables. EF does all that for you if you use Code First or Model First. In case of DB first, you build the DB and then have EF generate the needed classes for you (based on the DB tables). For Code first, you create the classes and then let EF generate the database for you. In Model First, you create an UML and EF will generate BOTH the DB and the classes.

Comment: Whichever option you take, it's important to not alter anything once EF has generated its content. If you do change it, you need to generate it again. This means you shouldn't be setting up the PK field in the DB (unless DB First), but rather telling EF there is a relation between the two entities. EF will then generate the needed FK fields and will handle everything for you if you just fill in the properties that it generated for you.

Comment: Sorry for the chain of comments!! @Flater I have worked it out. I've done some research, I am using Db first and the EF models were correct. However, SelectList was returning Id into the qualId field on employee and  my employee list view didn't include the newly generated "qualId" column (I know NOOB!!! I kept deleting the newly created employee value when I thought it had failed again so when i look at the actual database data, I didn't see any changes!!) I'm such an idiot! THANK YOU for you help, It works now!! amazing! I would up vote you if I had enough rep points. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help but i made a model class that creates multiple lists that i am going to use throughout my application one of the lists looks like:-

```html
SKTDATABASEEntities db = new SKTDATABASEEntities(); public List
<Department>Departments { get { return db.Departments.ToList(); } }
```

my classes name is ThingLists, then from there i instantiate it in my controller class as:-

```html
public ActionResult CreateTask() { ThingLists deps = new ThingLists(); var de = from t in deps.Departments select t.Department_Name; ViewData["depies"] = de;
```

and display it in my view like:-

```html
<label for="Task">Department</label>
<div class="editor-field">
  <%: Html.DropDownList( "lsttasks", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData[ "depies"], "Department"), new { id="drop1" })%>
    <br />
</div>
```

and that works perfectly at displaying my dropdownlist, someone suggested i use a javascript to assign selected item like:-

```js
  < script type = "text/javascript" >
    function onSelectedIndexChanged(select) {
      var text = $("drop1").valueOf();
      document.getElementById('drop1').innerHTML = text;
    } < /script>
```

and at that part i still get null in my controller maybe you can get somewhere from there to. :-) i'm still waiting for a response to my question as well but if someone responds with something i will share with you.

Comment: Sorry ignore my answer its not even an answer @stephen's answer works perfectly i just tried it thanks :-) I owe you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

@oli_taz use my code above and viewdata instead of viewbag i just had to modify my view to

```html
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Department,new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["depies"], "Department")) %>
```

it gets values from database table "departments" and populates list created in thinglists.cs and when i save it saves exactly my selected value to  my "tasks" table. I hope i explained it clear enough im kind of new.